# Recursively finding an ID's child and its underlying children

Tags: python, recursion, sqlite, tree

I created a table with two columns, "TOP" and "UNDER". TOP is the parent column with unique IDs, and UNDER contains underlying ID's, separated by ","s. The items in UNDER can also be a parent listed in the "TOP" column.

```
TOP     UNDER
----    --------
A       B
B       C,D
C       E,F
D       X,Y,Z
Z       J,K,L
E       V,M
F       G
```

I'm trying to create a function that will return all of a TOP's UNDER characters. i.e.: foo("C") = [E, V, M, F, G]. E has V, M. F has G. I'm lost on how to implement the recursion part. Everytime I try to implement it, I get an infinite loop.

```
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect("myTable.db") #Conn is a connection object that reps the db
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row #access columns of a query by name instead of index 
cursor = conn.cursor()   
id="C"    
cursor.execute("select * from myTable where id='%s'" %id)

def get_underlying(under_list, result_list=[]):
    if len(under_list) == 0:
        return result_list

    print("Query results for: select * from myTable where id='%s'" %(id))
    cursor.execute("select * from myTable where id='%s'" %id)
    r = cursor.fetchall()

    if r == []:
        return result_list

    under_list = r[0]['UNDER'].split(",") 
    for c in under_list:
        result_list.append(c)

    #???? lost on what to write
    if len(r) == 0:
        return
    elif len(r) == 1:
        return
    else
        return

print get_underlying("C")
```

Under_list will contain the current UNDER value. i.e. foo("D"), under_list = [X, Y, Z]. I then append each element to the result_list.

Am I approaching the problem/implementing it the wrong way? Could I have some help doing it correctly? I've been googling for hours, but I can't seem to word my search accurately enough to find a guide or solution.

Comment: Is `name` the same thing as `UNDER`?

Comment: Accually this is not a recursive function.

Comment: @smarx yes! sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Could you elaborate? I was planning on implementing the recursion under the #???? comment

Comment: The answer of @smarx is recursive and looks like good one!

Comment: Is it really necessary to have multiple values in the same column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Modified to handle cycles in the graph. ("TOP" and "UNDER" made me think this was a tree, but perhaps that's not a guarantee.)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('myTable.db')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()

def initialize():
    c.execute('create table myTable (ID text, UNDER text)')

    data = [
        ['A', 'B'],
        ['B', 'C,D'],
        ['C', 'E,F'],
        ['D', 'X,Y,Z'],
        ['Z', 'J,K,L'],
        ['E', 'V,M'],
        ['F', 'G,C'], # note the cycle!
    ]

    for top, under in data:
        c.execute('insert into myTable values (?, ?)', (top, under))

    conn.commit()

def get_all_reachable(node_id, found=None):
    if found is None:
        found = set()

    c.execute('select * from myTable where id=?', (node_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()

    if len(rows) == 0:
        return []

    for child in rows[0]['UNDER'].split(','):
        if child not in found:
            found.add(child)
            get_all_reachable(child, found)

    return found

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize()
    print(get_all_reachable('C'))

# Output:
# {'V', 'C', 'M', 'G', 'F', 'E'}
```

Comment: This looks good. My only concern is modifying a list while iterating over it, but perhaps my thinking is wrong here. I just always thought it was a no-no.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what the .extend does?

Comment: @Dan I may have edited my post since your comment... my original version used `children[:]` to make a new copy of the list before iteration, but I decided to change up the code to avoid that anyway.

Comment: @VeeCee Does this help? `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [4, 5, 6]; a.extend(b); a == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: @smarx say that 'B's children were [A,C,D], and you did a.extend(b), would there be duplicates since it goes in a circle? By the way, thank you so much! I didnt know you could do that

Comment: @VeeCee Oh, maybe I misunderstood the problem. There are potentially cycles in the graph? (E.g. "A --> B" and "B --> A"?)

Comment: @VeeCee See my edit, which handles cycles. This will also work fine for just regular duplicates appearing. (The `set` is what does that part.)

Comment: @smarx it was something i was wondering after i saw the .extend function! But thank you, it makes so much more sense now

Comment: @VeeCee To answer your direct question about extend: `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [3, 4, 5]; a.extend(b); a == [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`. Duplicates are definitely possible. (It just concatenates the lists together.)